# Weighted zonal statistics in Python

Tags: python, raster, zonal-statistics

I'm asking something similar than [Weighted zonal statistics in Python and/or R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169348/weighted-zonal-statistics-in-python-and-or-r). I know very well the R-side of this question, but I can't figure out the answer for Python.

So far I can compute [non-weighted zonal statistics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431122/extract-by-polygon-from-a-rioxarrays-raster):

```
import os
import rioxarray as rioxr
from rioxarray.merge import merge_arrays
from glob import glob
import geopandas

polys = geopandas.read_file(path_to_polygons)

files = glob(os.path.join('path/to/MOD13Q1/2002/033','*.hdf')) # example path
nbr_single = []
for file in files:
    with rioxr.open_rasterio(file) as src:
        NIR = getattr(src,'250m 16 days NIR reflectance')
        MIR = getattr(src,'250m 16 days MIR reflectance')
        nbr_single.append((NIR-MIR)/(NIR+MIR))

nbr_mosaic = merge_arrays(nbr_single) 

nbr_zonal = zonal_stats(
    vectors=polys,
    raster=nbr_mosaic[0,:,:].values, # since it's a 3D array
    affine=nbr_mosaic.rio.transform(),
    stats=["sum"],
)

# for testing in R
nbr_mosaic.rio.to_raster(os.path.join(some_path,'mosaic.tif'), compress='LZW')
```

And I tried a weighted and non-weighted approach in R:

```
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)

r <- rast('some_path/to/mosaic.tif')
sf <- read_sf(path_to_polygons)
v_ <- vect(path_to_polygons)

r1_values <- exact_extract(r,sf, fun = 'count')
r2_values <- extract(r,v_,length)
```

Where `r1_values` is a weigthed approach and `r2_values` is a non-weighted (although `terra::extract` can compute weighted statistic as well)

R's weighted count vs Python's non-weighted count:

[image]

R's non-weighted count vs Python's non-weighted count (minimal difference):

[image]

How can I compute a weight raster or directly weigthed zonal statistics in python?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, calling the commandline [`exactextract`](https://github.com/isciences/exactextract) tool via `subprocess` is about it. Though you have to compile it yourself. I hope you get an answer, this something myself and [others are interested](https://github.com/isciences/exactextract/issues/7) in also.

Comment: @user2856 thank you for the comment. I had `subprocess` in mind, although this means saving the raster to the disk. I will create a temporary folder for dumping those file and delete them after values extraction.